# How to obtain a surface plot of f(x, y, z) = c

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, surface

My equation is of the form :

```
exp(- (625*(x - 31/20)^2)/72   -  (625*(x - 981/250)^2)/72 - (625*(y - 461/100)^2)/72 -  (625*(y - 4797/1000)^2)/72 - (625*(z - 13207/1000)^2)/72 - (625*(z - 15177/1000)^2)/72) = 0.0005
```

It contains more terms in `x`, `y`, `z`, but they are of the same form 
`(625*((X - var)^2)/72)`   where `X` is `{x, y, z}` and inside the exponent.
Can I obtain 3d surface plot for this using this ?
Edit :: Can I instead have a plot with negative signs with Matlab avoiding too large values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create surface plots of implicit functions in Matlab like this:

```
f = @(x,y,z) exp((625*(x - 31/20)^2)/72 + (625*(x - 981/250)^2)/72 + (625*(y - 461/100)^2)/72 + (625*(y - 4797/1000)^2)/72 + (625*(z - 13207/1000)^2)/72 + (625*(z - 15177/1000)^2)/72) - 0.0005;

fimplicit3(f)
```

However in your case if you analyze [your equation in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp((625*(x%20-%2031%2F20)%5E2)%2F72%20%2B%20(625*(x%20-%20981%2F250)%5E2)%2F72%20%2B%20(625*(y%20-%20461%2F100)%5E2)%2F72%20%2B%20(625*(y%20-%204797%2F1000)%5E2)%2F72%20%2B%20(625*(z%20-%2013207%2F1000)%5E2)%2F72%20%2B%20(625*(z%20-%2015177%2F1000)%5E2)%2F72)%20-%200.0005) you can see that an alternate form of it is

[image: Alternate form of equation]

Matlab won't be able to plot this as it will interpret all calculated values as `Inf`. You would need to do some scaling of your function first.

You can check what the largest finite floating-point number in IEEE double precision is by using `realmax`. This will give you `1.7977e+308`.

**EDIT**

Matlab is able to plot some parts of the above function without the `8.12e1759` pre-factor. This will look like this:

[image: Surface plot of alternate form of function]

However as you can see Matlab is not able to display a surface at every position, as your function still behaves unexpectedly.

** EDIT 2 **

[Ander Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485872/ander-biguri) suggested to look at the function in the proximity of the origin.

If we do so like this:

```
f = @(x,y,z) exp(5/288 .* (2 .* x .* (500 .* x - 2737) + y .* (1000 .* y - 9407) + 8 .* z .* (125 .* z - 3548))) - 0.0005;

interval = [-0.6 0.6 -0.6 0.6 -0.6 0.6];

%interval2 = [-6 6 -6 6 -6 6];

fimplicit3(f,interval)

colorbar
```

and then look at the result from the top, we get a nice contour plot that looks like this:

[image: Contours plot in interval close to origin]

Notice that hear I also vectorized your function for performance reasons.

I can't explain why for larger intervals even parts that look fine in this smaller interval cannot be displayed by Matlab. For example if I use `interval2` instead the result looks like this:

[image: Contour plot for wider range]

Comment: Largest possible value in a double floating point format, not necessarily MATLAB.

Comment: I am new to matlab  do not have an good idea of function plotting . Is there a workaround? Another software / method?

Comment: This is actually more of a math question than a Matlab question. Maybe the guys over at math.stackexchange.com can help you with how to analyze your function in another way.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for the correction. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I wonder if some of the other function approximations are numerically stable around [0,0,0].